# Yeoman Angular dev environment with socket.io.js and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io, yeoman

I've got an angular app created with Yeoman that is working well in dev, on port 9000.

I've got a server-side node.js app running on port 3000.

I've installed socket.io on the NodeJS application.

Most of the JS in my angular app is in the `app` directory, but the socket.io.js is served up via node:

```
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This feels kind of wrong to me. Also, when I load socket.io and call `connect()` on the client side, it is trying to connect to localhost:9000, instead of localhost:3000

Is there a way to reconcile these two worlds? Do I need to serve my angular application from within node.js? I'm reluctant to lose live reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it all!

In your connect call make sure you connect to the websocket server, i.e.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

Loading the script from the socket server is fine. There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Issue with ports was due to an errant space in my URL. Things seem to be working great, thanks!